# ReactJs: How can I simplify this component so that I do not have to render my Modal and window component twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rendering

I want to simplify my component since I am returning my Modal, Window components and two divs twice, I would like to render them once and only alternate the title, barContainer and storageText divs when the mode prop is altered.

the only things that change inside it if the modalMode changes is this part:

(whats inside this divs.)

```
 <div className={styles.title}></div>
 <div className={styles.barContainer}>
 <span className={styles.storageText}>
 </div>
```

The rest (Modal, Window, menuButton and subtitle div) stay the same always.

Here is my component:

```
const modalMode: StorageWarningModalTypes = "STORAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED";

type Props = {
    storageUsed: number;
    storageAvailable: number;
    fileSize: number;
    mode: string;
    percentageUsed: number;
    disableProButton: boolean;
    onClose: Function;
};
```

```
const StorageModals = ({
    storageUsed,
    storageAvailable,
    fileSize,
    mode,
    percentageUsed,
    disableProButton,
    onClose,
}: Props) => {
    if (!storageUsed || storageUsed < 0) storageUsed = 0;
    if (!storageAvailable || storageAvailable < 0) storageAvailable = 0;

    if (mode === modalMode) {
        return (
            <div>
                <Modal className={styles.container} onClickOutside={onClose}>
                    <Window
                        title={" "}
                        maxHeight={MODAL_MAX_HEIGHT}
                        className={styles.storageModal}
                        showCloseButton={true}
                        onClose={onClose}
                    >
                        <div className={styles.cardContainer}>

                            **<div className={styles.title}></div>
                            <div className={styles.barContainer}>
                                <span className={styles.storageText}>
                            </div>**

---> this part stays the same:

                            <div className={styles.subtitle}></div>
                            <MenuButton></MenuButton>
                        </div>
                    </Window>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
```

```
    } else
        return (
            <div>
                <Modal className={styles.container} onClickOutside={onClose}>
                    <Window
                        title={" "}
                        maxHeight={MODAL_MAX_HEIGHT}
                        className={styles.storageModal}
                        showCloseButton={true}
                        onClose={onClose}
                    >
                        
                        <div className={styles.cardContainer}>

                            **<div className={styles.title}></div>
                            <div className={styles.barContainer}>
                                <span className={styles.storageText}>
                            </div>**

                            <div className={styles.subtitle}></div>
                            <MenuButton></MenuButton>
                        </div>
                    </Window>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
};

export default StorageModals;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the conditional `return` and instead, if it's the classnames you want to change, use conditional classnames:

```
 <div className={mode === modalMode ? styles.title : 'your other classname'}></div>
 <div className={mode === modalMode ? styles.barContainer : 'your other classname'}>
   <span className={mode === modalMode ? styles.storageText : }>
 </div>
```

or, if it's the content inside the div you want to change, you can conditionally render content with a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) as well:

```
<div>{condition ? 'some content' : 'other content'}</div>
```